# Dropzone.js not sending image file data to laravel controller function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, dropzone.js

I am using Laravel 5 and have a form where I am using dropzone.js as below,

```
<form method="post" action="{{url('/example/fileupload')}}" 
enctype="multipart/form-data" class="dropzone" id="my-awesome-dropzone">

    @csrf


<input type="submit">

</form>
```

and the code Laravel controller function is

```
  public function fileupload(Request $request)
    {


$file = Input::file('file');
$destinationPath = 'uploads';

$filename = str_random(12);

$upload_success = Input::file('file')->move($destinationPath, $filename);

if( $upload_success ) {
   return Response::json('success', 200);
} else {
   return Response::json('error', 400);
}

    }
```

But after dropping the image in dropzone area and clicking on submit button it shows this error,

> Call to a member function move() on null

Can anyone suggest what's going wrong or providing the solution? Thanks

P.S I am using below tutorial as suggested in dropzone.js official site for Laravel server side config.
https://maxoffsky.com/code-blog/howto-ajax-multiple-file-upload-in-laravel/